# To press ones forefinger onto someone's shoulder

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the expression for ***touching someone with your forefinger or hand*** to, for example to get their attention, to wake them up, or to mark your presence.

Comment: Normally that's referred to as "tapping on the shoulder" -- "He tapped Fred on the shoulder to get his attention."

Comment: Or you can touch someone on the shoulder.  That is more gentle than *tap* and it accomplishes the same thing.  It is understood that it is done to get their attention. ...  Now, for waking someone up, you may need to *shake* his shoulder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how, and where on the body, you touch them. There are three main ways to do do this

1. [Tap](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tap), to give one or more light blows, usually on the shoulder.
2. [Prod](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prod), to jab with a finger or an implement such as a ruler or a stick. The jab can be gentle or it can be harder (sometimes referred to as more sharp), it's still a prod.
3. [Stroke](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stroke) (3rd definition of the noun,1st definition of the verb), this is a gentle moving of the hand or fingers over a part of the body, usually an arm or hand. Strokes on other parts of the body are more intimate.

Examples of the usage are

1. "I gave him a tap on the shoulder"
2. "I prodded his arm sharply with my pen"
3. "I stroked her hand gently"

There are many ways to add subtle changes to these statements; there's probably enough material for a book, and the book would almost certainly miss some things. This is just a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Tapping is probably the best answer, but you can also poke him with your finger, just to give you another option.

Comment: This is the best one if you want to express that it is annoying to the person on the receiving end.  This one is done face to face.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for the supplement

Comment: @habibhassani - I just noticed I didn't write my comment very clearly.  I meant to say that "poking" indicates that it is annoying and done face to face.  "Tapping" is more innocuous and could be from the side or the back.

Comment: @aparente001 i got the annoying part but not the face to face, so thank you for clarification.

Comment: @habibhassani - and then "jabbing" would be *incredibly* annoying.  Also done face to face.